# Magento Theme not applying on 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, parent-child-theme, theme-fallback, js-css

I am using Magento 1.9 and using the theme [elegance](https://themeforest.net/item/elegance-magento-responsive-jewelry-theme/16346767)
. I have installed the theme manually from extracting the files in root directory and by following the instructions in the site domain. But my theme isn't loading correctly and if I check in the developer's console. I see the theme source file is just `skin/frontend/` instead of `skin/frontend/luxury/`. All the CSS and page contens are also not working properly. You can check here - http://stuffkart.com

Also, some js and css files are loading from `skin/frontend/base/`

I am a bit new to Magento. Searched a lot, but can't find anything that could've solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your admin under `System -> Config -> Design` and under the `Package` and `Theme` section make sure you have the theme defined. In your case i'm not 100% when this needs to be set to, as i don't know the directory structure that was installed and i can't find the documentation on the theme forest link you posted.

If you have a path like `skin/frontend/theme/name` then `theme` will need to be in the `Package` area (in the pic i have rwd there, so this would replace) and `name` would in under `Theme` in all the areas (if there are not translations you can leave that blank).

If you have a path like `skin/frontend/default/theme` then you want to leave `Package` blank and only place `theme` in the `Theme` section.

[image]

As an FYI, the reason some of the files are trying to read from `skin/frontend/base/` is the fallback system Magento uses. If a file is being called from `skin/frontend/theme/name/js/somefile.js` and that file is not found in that directory, Magento will automatically look in the next `package` down from it to see if it's there, with the last `package` being `base`. So there is no call to a file in the base folder, but since the fallback sees base as the last place to check, the error sent to the browser is for a file with that call. This can get confusing at first as you might be tempted to look for that file in `base`, but the theme settings will tell you the truth of where files are being drawn from on a Magento install.

Comment: My directory is `skin/frontend/luxury/default/` , so this is how my theme settings looks now - https://i.imgur.com/NuiBbyk.png ,  but it's still not working. 
Also, if the theme is missing correspondent files and going into fallback. Should I report this to the theme company? It's a premium theme, what else can I do to fix the missing files issue?

Comment: That is the correct way to set up the theme, but i just looked at your site and your path is `http://stuffkart.com/magento/skin/frontend/base/default/favicon.ico` so i think you have the wrong settings in your base url. Under the base url you should see this `{{unsecure_base_url}}skin/` and this `{{secure_base_url}}skin/`. If that is correct, you should check to make sure your url in those fields is not `http://stuffkart.com/magento/`.

Comment: Yes, they were set at that setting. Fortunately, I reinstalled the theme and it's working now. I am not quite sure why, cause I have reinstalled it before also. But it seems to be working now. Thanks a lot for your assistance, got some knowledge for future reference. ^_^

Comment: good to hear it's working now!